# node js synchronous for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, synchronous

```
  db.collection("influencer_chat_db").find({}).toArray(function(err, chatResult){

  for(i=0;i< chatResult.length;++i){
    console.log("A");
    await db.collection("chatNewmsgNotification").find({"room":chatResult[i].room}).toArray(await function(err,notificationResult){
      console.log("B")
    });
  }})
```

I want to retrieve data from collection "chatNewmsgNotification" using a for loop, However the executions is happening synchronous format. I made the code in easy way to understand, the expected execution and output is A B A B. Currently i am getting as A A B B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `callback` function is not bound to the `promise` so once the `promise` returns theres still an unknown (small) amount of time untill the `callback` function is called, which is why the loop manages to be faster.

You have two easy fixes:

1. Change the find to work without a callback:

```
db.collection("influencer_chat_db").find({}).toArray(async function (err, chatResult) {

    for (i = 0; i < chatResult.length; ++i) {
        console.log("A");
        await db.collection("chatNewmsgNotification").find({"room": chatResult[i].room}).toArray();
        console.log("B")
    }
});
```

2. If for some reason you do enjoy the `callback` functionality then wrap it with a `promise`:

```
db.collection("influencer_chat_db").find({}).toArray(async function (err, chatResult) {

    for (i = 0; i < chatResult.length; ++i) {
        console.log("A");

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                db.collection("chatNewmsgNotification").find({"room":chatResult[i].room}).toArray(await function(err,notificationResult){
                    console.log("B");
                    resolve();
                });
            } catch (e) {
              reject(e)  
            } 
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: That second code block can't possibly be right.  You have three `await` statements and a custom made promise.  Something isn't right there with all that.  You should probably just remove that whole manually promisified option.  The DB supports promises.  Just use them appropriately, don't wrap your own.  Wrapping your own promises where they are not needed is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @tom slabbaert, Actually, First answer didn't work for me, But 2nd working 100% fine. Thanks